# Google Chrome embedded video player documentation

Tags: html, google-chrome, specifications, video-player, embedded-video

Is there a place I can go look at how the embedded Chrome video player works, like how its HTTP get requests will look and what's it expecting and return, and what kind of caching strategies it employs and if they can be overriden.

Is there anything of that sort to specify its behaviour? Os since it supports the HTML5 video tag, does the video tag actually define that?